# Does dative bonding cause polarity?

Tags: bond

When two atoms form a dative non-polar bond, does the one that shares the couple of electrons acquire a +δ charge and the other a -δ charge?
I have been told that in a dative polar bond the charge fraction is twice as much as in a normal covalent bond, but, since the electrons behave right the same way, shouldn't that imply the dative bond itself creates a charge?

Comment: Generally dative bonds form to reduce charge densities. Examples such as carbon monoxide and zwitterionic aminoacids are of lower polarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unequal sharing of electrons can indeed induce polarity. A clear-cut example comes from [ozone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ozone), the triatomic form of oxygen. The referenced Wikipedia article reports a dipole moment of 0.53 D (citing [[1]](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.433909)) despite all atoms being identical, an unusual feature for a molecule with only one element.

The three atoms in the ozone molecule form a bent chain in which the central atom shares three electron pairs and each of the end atoms shares only a pair and a half (there are two equivalent contributing structures in which one end atom shares two electron pairs and the other shares one). The molecular orbital structure of ozone also shows the central atom giving more electronic charge to the end atoms than vice versa in the three-center, four-electron pi bond. And, indeed, this unequal sharing of electrons creates a charge separation and a dipole moment as documented by Wikipedia.

**Cited Reference**

1. Kenneth M. Mack, J. S. Muenter; "Stark and Zeeman properties of ozone from molecular beam spectroscopy". *J. Chem. Phys.* 15 June 1977; ***66** (12): 5278–5283. https://doi.org/10.1063/1.433909